# Deduce the Conclusion for the Premises

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have done this problem over 20 times now and am officially stumped. The instructions are **Deduce the conclusion for the premises, giving a reason using the rule of inferences for each step**.

a) p -> q

b) r∨s

c) ∼s→∼t

d) ∼q∨s

e) ∼s

f) ∼p∧r→u

g) w∨t

h) ∴ u ∧ w

Any help would be appreciated! I don't even know where to start. Thanks!

Comment: The phrasing sounds fairly strange, but I think the triple-dot symbol in the (h) item means that you're supposed to construct a proof that deduces $u\land w$ **from** (not "for") the premises (a) through (g).

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's fairly simple to construct a derivation by starting at the end of it:

- In order to conclude $u\land w$, we need to establish $u$ and $w$ separately.
- We need to conclude $u$. The only premise that even mentions $u$ is (f), so we'll need to establish $\neg p$ and $r$ separately.
- We need to conclude $\neg p$. The only premise that even mentions $p$ except for (f) is (a), so we'll have to conclude $\neg p$ by contraposing (a). Therefore we'll need to establish $\neg q$.
- We need to conclude $\neg q$. The only premise that even mentions $q$ except for (a) is (d), so *(and so forth and so forth)*

Eventually you'll find that everything you need is ultimately a consequence of $\neg s$, which is an explicit assumption.